# Find sum of first $n$ terms of the series : $1+\frac{1^3+2^3}{1+2}+\frac{1^3+2^3+3^3}{1+2+3}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The main question is:

> Find sum of first $n$ terms of the series : $1+\frac{1^3+2^3}{1+2}+\frac{1^3+2^3+3^3}{1+2+3}+\dots$

My approach:

Initially, nothing clicked, so I went forward with simplifying the series.
So, we get, after simplifying,

$S$(The sum of series) = $1+3+6+10+15+21+\dots$

So, I try to write $S$ as,

$1+(4-1)+(9-3)+(16-6)+\dots$

So what I finally get is,

$S$=$(1+4+9+16+25+\dots) - (1+3+6+10+\dots)$

Therefore,

$$2S=\sum_{n=1}^n{n^2}$$

Thus,

$S$ = $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$

But, the answer given in my textbook is

$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$

My answer is not matching. Please help me by pointing out my mistake or providing a new approach and solution altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

$$1^3+2^3+...+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} \\
1+2+3+..+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

**Edit:**
You can then use the identity (thanks to Winther for fixing the typo)
$$n(n+1)= \frac{1}{3} \left[(n+1)^3-n^3 \right]-\frac{1}{3}$$
to evaluate the new sum.

Comment: Also useful is $1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Comment: I am aware of these theorems, but I'm not understanding where to apply them

Comment: @AksharGandhi Your numerators are the first formula, the denominators are the second for $n=2,3,...$.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Winther Done, thank you.

Comment: Does it become a telescoping series?

Comment: @AksharGandhi After you use the second hint, it becomes telescopic +constant sum....

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thanks to all for your approach and time! (+1).

Comment: Hm so why is the $2S$ part wrong? It's simply $S=(1+4+9+16+25+\dots) - (1+3+6+10+\dots)$, $S=1+3+6+10+15+21+\dots$, so $2S= 1+4+9+\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that

$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
and 
$$y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$
so 
$$\frac{y_n}{x_n}=x_n$$
so you need to recall the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
to compute the desired sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k}{x_k}$.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: My question has been solved. Thank you for your approach and time!